Rigify rig moves the body but not the head
I used rigify to rig a human character model. After generating the rig it seemed to work fine until I tried moving the face and head in pose mode and nothing moved. The rest of the body works perfectly fine from the neck below. I parented with automatic weights and tried parenting with different weights and it still didn't change.
Moving the body but head doesn't move

Head and face don't move with rig
(Blend file: https://blend-exchange.com/b/J4bKXjjS/)

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.



Some bones (i,e. lips) are in the wrong place, so before weighting you should consider to edit the Metarig, then regenerate the rig, but that is not what is causing the problem.

When you try to do automatic weighting of the face, the system console throws an error: Warning: Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones (a little yellow alert appears on the bottom of the 3D window).
This is due to the intricate region of the nostrils, which do overlap.

You can solve in two ways:

go to sculpt mode, choose the smooth brush and paint over the inner nostrils until errors are smoothed out, then use again Ctrl P  > Automatic weights.

if you need to preserve the mesh as it is (not your case, I think), go to edit mode, select all the problematic areas and press P > Separate, then parent the main mesh with auto weights, then use Ctrl J to rejoin the two meshes (select inner nostrils first, then main mesh). Then use manual weight paint or direct weight assign in edit mode to add weight to the joined area.




Thanks, it worked. I don't know why some of the bones were out of place in that file but it works perfectly now.
